# Anti-aliasing of clipped image

Tags: ios, uiimage, antialiasing, uibezierpath

I have been trying to experiment with clipping an image in a circular path. But, I can't seem to get the clipping path to be anti-aliased.

I have tried a few different things, but none seem to work. How do I get the clipped image to be anti-aliased?

```
UIImage*originalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"grandpa.png"];
int minWidth = originalImage.size.width;
bool isWidth = YES;
if(minWidth > originalImage.size.height){
        minWidth = originalImage.size.height;
        isWidth = NO;
}

UIBezierPath *path;
if(isWidth)
    path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(0, (originalImage.size.height - minWidth)/2, minWidth, minWidth)];
else
    path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake((originalImage.size.width - minWidth)/2, 0, minWidth, minWidth)];


UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(originalImage.size, NO, 0);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context, true);
CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, true);
[path addClip];
[originalImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
UIImage *maskedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

//This is based on the full size image
CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, maskedImage.size.width + 2, maskedImage.size.height + 2);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageRect.size);
[maskedImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(1,1,maskedImage.size.width,maskedImage.size.height)];
maskedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

[image: Aliasing Image]

Comment: I have also been looking for a solution...

Comment: I've get a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14071278/384864

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem and it took me several hours on google and debugging but I finally figured this one out.

Whats happening is when you set the `maskedImage` to your `imageView.image` there is some resizing going on which includes the rounded clipping (on the image) and the result comes out funky.

A small example would be if your `imageView` has a bounds of 100x100 and the `maskedImage` has a bounds of 300x300 then when the `imageView.image` sets the `maskedImage` there will be reduced resizing to fit the image. This reduced sizing wont updated the rounded clipping, so your result is what appears to be jagged edges. If before you add the rounded clipping you scale the `maskedImage` to a size close to the `imageView` then your rounded edges will look exactly how you want!